# Extracting Arrays While Simultaneously Removing Blank Columns

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I have a complex excel spreadsheet that I'm trying to ingest and cleanse via xlrd.  The existing spreadsheet is really designed to be more of a "readable" document, but I'm tasked with ingesting it as a data source.  The trouble is that there is frequently lots of spacing between the field names and the actual data.  Ultimately I'd like to read in the contents of the excel file, process it, and write a simplified file with just the data.  Any ideas?

For example:

**Have:**

[image]

**Want:**

[image]

Here's the example spreadsheet: [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhjf3wpxranns1i/simple.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Take a look: https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.empty_cell-variable

Comment: Why not export it as a csv file and use pythons csv reader?